# Create iso with bootable USB

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

I have a very old machine that won't boot from USB.  Nothing to do with the USB - the BIOS does not have any features for booting off USB.

I am looking for an .iso which contains a USB driver which will allow me to boot off a usb drive.

Please do not send me links of how to create a bootable USB drive or how to put an ISO on a USB drive.  I did a search for the iso I'm looking for and the first 100 hits was how to create a bootable USB drive.  That is not what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know what the link is for a bootable CD which will then boot off USB.  Alternatively, I don't mind getting my hands dirty - how do I create such an ISO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: If your system can't boot from USB, it means it can't boot from USB. Period. there is no workaround. You can install Ubuntu from a HDD, etc. If it is an old machine, probably Lubuntu is the right choice. Lubuntu iso can be burnt to a DVD. Is this question Ubuntu related at all?

Comment: Other than me trying to boot off a USB drive that contains a Ubuntu installation, no.  I used to have a CD that allowed me to boot off the USB drive but I've misplaced it.  I got it off the internet when installing warty warthog.  I'm looking for a disk image that will boot an image from a USB drive.

Comment: @K7AAY what good would that do?  The CD drive cannot read a DVD.

Comment: How about using the Network Installer ISO which will fit on a CD? http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/

Comment: I might try that just for the fun of it.  Problem is because it is an old machine, the network card sometimes gives up under heavy traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plop Boot Manager

Sounds like you are looking for **Plop Boot Manager**:

https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html

It can be installed on a CD/DVD, (or Floppy Disk), and used to boot a Live USB.

Plop can also be installed on a corner of your hard drive.